# How Do I Properly Initialize RxDB in a Vue App with global

Tags: vue.js, rxdb

I'm trying out RxDB for the first time in a Vue 3 app, and getting started is a bit more tricky than I expected (and it's probably my fault).

I installed RxDB with NPM in my project (`"rxdb": "^9.20.0"`), then I did this in my `main.js` file:

```
import { createRxDatabase, RxDatabase } from 'rxdb'
 
const db = await createRxDatabase({
  name: 'MyApp', adapter: 'idb'
})

console.dir(db)
```

I then get this error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: global is not defined

So I check the docs [and found this](https://rxdb.info/install.html#npm) that I need a global polyfill like this:

```
(window as any).global = window;
(window as any).process = {
    env: { DEBUG: undefined },
};
```

That looks to be an example using Typescript from Angular. When I try it in Vue, I then get this error:

```
Invalid assignment target
3  |  import { createRxDatabase, RxDatabase } from 'rxdb'
4  |  
5  |  const db = await createRxDatabase({
   |             ^
6  |    name: 'Avid', adapter: 'idb'
7  |  })
```

10 minutes in and I'm already a mess.  Can someone show me how to properly start up RxDB in a Vue app?

Comment: have you tried window.global=window;

Answer (score 2):

You can't use await in root.
It must be inside async function.

```
let db

async function initDb() {
  db = await createRxDatabase(...)
}

initDb()
```